# Inkscape - Gradients and saving as vector graphics

Tags: inkscape, gradient, eps, pixelation

I have a vector `eps` plot on which I add gradient shade in Inkscape. However, when I save as `eps` again, the gradient part of the plot is pixelated.

Does anyone has solution for this, that is to save a gradient in vector form?

[image]

Comment: Related question: http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=347

Comment: A solution yes, don't use EPS.  Use SVG.

Comment: If you put the gradient below, you can: 'Edit > Make a bitmap copy' and then 'Path > Trace bitmap (with enough colors)' to get a gradient that consists of multiple objects, each with a simple, flat, one-color-only fill.

Comment: @BillyKerr: I need submit the figure in a journal article, where they accept only eps or png images.